# How can I programmatically resize SVG file with svgwrite in python?

Tags: python, svgwrite

My current workflow is using svgwrite to generate my svg file and import into inkscape to resize and align to export to gcode. I'm looking for a way to do this programmatically via cli. I've tried a couple svg-resizing repo's from github however they don't work well shrinking and svgwrite doesn't have a fixed output size option. I've thought of maybe creating an empty rectangle of the size I require with svgwrite's drawing class but I'm not sure how to add my svg file and have it fit to its container (the empty rectangle).

Any and all suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't the `size` parameter to the `Drawing` constructor let you set a fixed output size?

Comment: @rici this would appear to be the case however it's overridden if the drawing is bigger than the defined size, at least it is for me

Comment: OK, I guess what you're trying for here is to set a canvas size independent of the drawing coordinates, or in other words to have the bounding box (computed after the drawing is complete) automatically resized to a given canvas size. SVG doesn't feature automatic resizing, afaik; in a web browser, the image will be clipped to the viewbox, not shrunk. And I don't think svgwrite can compute the bounding box, because you can't really do that computation without rendering and svgwrite isn't a renderer. But it should be possible to do with two passes through a renderer.

Comment: ... Because you can set the viewbox with pdfwrite, and you can shrink (or expand) the viewbox to the canvas size with SVG. You just need to know the bounding box first, which is why I think it would take two passes. (But I'm not an SVG expert. I've used it to do some graph renders, but that's it.)

Comment: So you'r suggesting converting it to pdf with a viewbox then convert back to svg? I'm trying to setup a parsing server that's cli only so rendering wouldn't really be possible

Comment: Doesn't have to be pdf and there's no need to convert it back; the only change you need to make is to adda viewbox, which you should be able to do without regenerating the SVG. "All" you need is some kind of renderer from which you can extract the bounding box after rendering. Could be inkscape itself, which is scriptable although the last time I tried I found the documentation frustrating. Or it could be a headless web browser, which can also be a bit frustrating. Stock up on anti-frustrants, is my advice :-). If I come up with a better idea, I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just discovered I can directly modify the size of the svg via it's height and width properties when opening it in notepad++ or similar. However the only restraint to this is the viewbox positioning I think. But much closer solution